# сделать так, чтобы в поле ввода нельзя было стирать символ после ввода

Tags: javascript, html, input

у меня есть поле input, в него вводятся цифры. вот код:

```
<input class="field" id="number" type="text" placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000">
```

нужно сделать так, чтобы введенный символ нельзя было стереть. то есть, вводят первую цифру ,она "замораживается" и не стирается. не могу додуматься, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let input = document.querySelector('.field');
let lastValue = '';

input.addEventListener( 'input', ()=>{
  if( input.value.length < lastValue.length ){
    input.value = lastValue;
  } else {
    lastValue = input.value;
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="field" id="number" type="text" placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#number');
let input_value = '';

input.oninput = (e) => {
    input_value.length > e.target.value.length
        ? (e.target.value = input_value)
        : (input_value = e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<input class="field" id="number" type="tel" placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000">
```